# Pytorch Dataloader not spliting data into batch

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I have dataset class like this:

```
class LoadDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, label):
        self.data = data
        self.label = label
    def __len__(self):
        dlen = len(self.data)
        return dlen
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data, self.label
```

then i load my image dataset which have [485, 1, 32, 32] shape

```
train_dataset = LoadDataset(xtrain, ytrain)
print(len(train_dataset))
# output 485
```

then i load the data with `DataLoader`

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32)
```

and then i iterate the data:

```
for epoch in range(num_epoch):
        for inputs, labels in train_loader:   
            print(inputs.shape)
```

the output prints `torch.Size([32, 485, 1, 32, 32])`, it should be `torch.Size([32, 1, 32, 32])`,

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__getitem__` method should return 1 data piece, you returned all of them.

Try this:

```
class LoadDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, label):
        self.data = data
        self.label = label
    def __len__(self):
        dlen = len(self.data)
        llen = len(self.label)  # different here
        return min(dlen, llen)  # different here
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index], self.label[index]  # different here
```